# How To Set Textbox1 Value Into Formula Field Of Cystal Reports

Tags: c#, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I want to set textbox1 value into formula field of crystal reports and Utilise the same value into crystal reports.

Suppose my Textbox1 value is **“12000”** and I want to set it to formula field and utilize the same into crystal reports. Is it possible?. And yes then How?.

Note: **textbox1 located on top of CrystalReportviewer1.**

### Solution

It is very simple just create the instance of the reports class and set the textBox value  in your crystalreportviewer source as under:

```
PLCrystReport plc = new PLCrystReport();
plc.DataDefinition.FormulaFields["ttt"].Text = "" + textBox1.Text + "";
```

For above first you have to create the formula field in your crystal reports and set the above code then after copy your formula field to your crystal reports. It will shows the specified value of textbox into formula field.

Note ["ttt"] is the formula field name. which provided into crystal reports.

Comment: in vs2015 this is FormulaFields.Item("ttt").Text

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim RptForm As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument

Dim T As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.TextObject

RptForm = New MyCrystalReport()

T = RptForm.ReportDefinition.Sections(0).ReportObjects("TXTCNAME")

T.Text = DTPTDate.Value
```

Here TXTCNAME is the name of textbox present in Sections(0) of Crystal Report

MyCrystalReport is the crystal Report you want to use.

Answer (score 1):

when the Crystal report **formula field** is a **DateTime** , then the following code will helps you:

```
CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument rd = new ReportDocument();
rd.Load("AgedItems_3.rpt");
try
{
string datetext = RunDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
rd.DataDefinition.FormulaFields["ProcessDate"].Text = "#"+datetext+"#";
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}


crystalReportViewer2.ReportSource = rd;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add '' at between the text value ex: `reportDoc.DataDefinition.FormulaFields("NameOfFormula").Text = "'Value'"`
 . this must work fine.

Answer (score 0):

First create an instance of your report class, then access the member variable and use that variable in your main interface.

Suppose I have a report class Called ReportView(), there I declared a member variable like

```
public CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument rptDocument;
```

Now in your report showing interface, create an instance of ReportView and follow:

```
ReportView rptView = new ReportView();
rptView.rptDocument.DataDefinition.FormulaFields["formulaName"].Text = "'" + txt.Text + "'";
```

Here, `txt` is a textbox that contain a value and `formulaName` is a formula created in the report design.