# formula field not display passed value in cr for asp.net 2010

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports, report

It is my first question,  I am using asp.net 2010 and trying to pass a value to formula  field  , the value is passed,  I can catch  it in a msg  box, but it does not appear  in the report.  I use the  same code in vb.net without any problem.

My code

```
Report.Datadifinition.formulafield(1).Text= "'value'"
```

I am sure that this code has no problems, may it be caused  by crystal software  itself ?
Any help  please

Thank  you in advance.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10926803/how-to-set-textbox1-value-into-formula-field-of-cystal-reports

Answer (score 0):

this is a formula field creation sample in c# ,i hope it can help you:

```
FormulaFieldDefinitions definitions = report1.FormulaFields;
string formulaText = "IF " + report1.Database.Tables[1].Fields[3].Name 
+ " > 10 THEN" + report1.Database.Tables[1].Fields[2].Name;
definitions.Add("Test", formulaText);
report1.Sections[1].AddFieldObject(definitions[1], 0, 0);
```

Comment: Thank you Hamidreza ,  but this code is not in the range of my problem, thanks again.